# Is visual studio 2008 compatible with windows 7 Home Basic/Premium?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

Can I install Visual studio 2008 with sp1 on Windows 7 Home Basic/Premium? I want also install silverlight tools and RIA services on window 7?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can install Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 7.  You can also install Silverlight Tools and RIA Services on Windows 7.

Comment: Vote goes to you. I've never worked with the latter two so I wasn't sure!

Comment: I've used Silverlight Tools before, so I know they work.  RIA Tools download says Windows 7 is a supported OS, but haven't used it personally: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=76bb3a07-3846-4564-b0c3-27972bcaabce&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2008 and many other devel tools/environments on Win7 Pro and Ultimate. Everything works great. The same should be with other Win7 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have VS 2008 Professional with SP1 installed on Windows 7 64 bit and it works just fine.  I also installed VS 2010 Express along side it on the same machine and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just be aware that SQL Server 2008 Express (that comes with VS 2008) is not supported on Windows 7 and so you should install SQL Server 2008 SP1 after the install if you need SQL Server.